# Can you actually evade The Covenant patrol in Halo?

Tags: halo-combat-evolved

In Halo Combat Evolved I never managed to evade the patrol that searched for the survivors in the beginning of the Chapter 2

Is it possible to evade it completely without getting spotted? Especially in Legendary? (I have finshed the same chapter in all difficulties but always got spotted)

I have tried hiding in anywhere possible. The closest to the success was hiding at the waterfall but I got spotted again while trying to push forward.

I most of the time get spotted by the enemy aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

You can, in fact, evade the patrol banshees and Spirit Dropship. It involves patience and sneaking from tree to tree along the path.
 Below is a Youtube video (it's old and quite laggy, but it shows it). Detailing the moves.

Comment: Not exactly what I want but still thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices there:

1. Cross the bridge, get into a V shaped corner and then start hitting one of the ships with assault rifle. The second one will go away once one ship falls. If you lose significant health, defeat the aliens near your capsule and get the health boost and come back to the original V corner to move upwards.
2. Cross the bridge and keep moving upwards ignoring the patrol ships and the aliens behind. Jumping can speed you up. Engage in the fight with the aliens you meet uphill and the patrol ships would go away.

Answer (score -2):

The closest I have been able to get is doing out triggering the event, and then I go back and hid in the pod